# When the Api returned data,the data is not able to be set in the Object's datatype in angular

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular6

I have a normal input fields like this:

[image]

When i click on that "+" button this action happens and the service class is called as I have simple Json data arriving.I want to assign the   **selectionCustomOffice.custOfficeName=json data's.custOffcName;** but I am getting the **undefined** result.

```
addedO(selectionCustomOffice:SelectionCustomOffice){
     this.scoe=true;

   this.selectionCustomOfficeService.getSingleCustomOffice(selectionCustomOffice.customOfficeId).subscribe((data)=>{
        console.log("entered");

         selectionCustomOffice.custOfficeName=data.custOffcName;
         console.log( selectionCustomOffice.custOfficeName);
          },(error)=>{
         console.log(error);
       });

 this.empList.push(selectionCustomOffice);
 this.selectionCustomOffice=new SelectionCustomOffice();

 console.log(this.empList);
}



this.selectionCustomOfficeService.getSingleCustomOffice(selectionCustomOffice.customOfficeId).subscribe((data)=>{
        console.log("entered");

         selectionCustomOffice.custOfficeName=data.custOffcName;
         console.log( selectionCustomOffice.custOfficeName);
          },(error)=>{
         console.log(error);
       });
```

[image]

SelectionCustomOffice.ts

```
export class SelectionCustomOffice {
    id: number;
    fromDate: string;
    toDate: string;
    consignmentNo: number;
    selectionId: number;
    customOfficeId: number;
    custOfficeName: string;

}
```

The form to send data is: I have used this field `custom office` as select field.

```
<div class="form-group row">
   <div class="col-md-4">
      <label>Custom Office</label>
   </div>
   <div class="col-md-2">
      <label>From Date</label>
   </div>
   <div class="col-md-2">
      <label>To Date</label>
   </div>
   <div class="col-md-4">Consignment No</div>
   <div class="col-md-4">
      <select class="form-control" id="customOfficeId" required [(ngModel)]="selectionCustomOffice.customOfficeId" name="customOfficeId"
      >
      <option *ngFor="let title of customoffices" [value]="title.custOfficeId">{{title.custOffcName}}</option>
      </select>
   </div>
   <div class="col-md-2">
      <input type="date" class="form-control" id="fromDate" required [(ngModel)]="selectionCustomOffice.fromDate" name="fromDate" />
   </div>
   <div class="col-md-2">
      <input type="date" class="form-control" id="toDate" required [(ngModel)]="selectionCustomOffice.toDate" name="toDate" />
   </div>
   <div class="col-md-3">
      <input type="number" class="form-control" id="consignmentNo" required [(ngModel)]="selectionCustomOffice.consignmentNo" name="consignmentNo">
   </div>
   <div class="col-md-1">
      <button type="button" (click)="addedO(selectionCustomOffice)">+</button>
   </div>
</div>
```

service class

```
getSingleCustomOffice(id: number): Observable<any> {
    return this.http.get(`${this.baseUrl}/${id}`, { responseType: 'text' });
  }
```

Comment: have you confirmed that custOffcName has a value beforehand?

Comment: no no so i want to assign it to the json data i get after calling api

Comment: try by putting this code inside subscribe => this.empList.push(selectionCustomOffice);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you have a small problem - You are reading your response as `text`

```
getSingleCustomOffice(id: number): Observable<any> {
    return this.http.get(`${this.baseUrl}/${id}`, { responseType: 'text' });
  }
```

Remove the `{ responseType: 'text' }` from the `http` call or use `JSON.parse(data)` when you are reading data - `{ responseType: 'text' }` this will return your response as `string`

Try like this if you want your response as `text`

```
this.selectionCustomOfficeService.getSingleCustomOffice(selectionCustomOffice.customOfficeId).subscribe((data)=>{
        console.log("entered");
         let outPut = JSON.parse(data);
         selectionCustomOffice.custOfficeName=outPut.custOffcName;
         console.log( selectionCustomOffice.custOfficeName);
          },(error)=>{
         console.log(error);
       });
```

I think this might solve your problem - Happy coding !!